# Set-theoretic notation: cardinality of infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It seems nonstandard to use vertical bars $| \cdot|$ to denote the cardinality of a potentially infinite set, but the lecture notes I'm working through do so. It also uses $\leq$, $>$, and $<$ notation, but doesn't necessarily define them. My understanding from reading some questions on here is that the notation can be read as follows.

> We say $|S| \leq |T|$ if there is an injection $S \hookrightarrow T$. This then means $|S| < |T|$ or $|S| = |T|$, where the latter means means that there is a bijection between $S$ and $T$. The former means there is no bijection; since there is an injection $S \to T$, it must mean that there is no surjection from $S \to T$. In this sense, $T$ is "larger" than $S$, but in the infinite sense, it doesn't really make sense to talk about the size of a set in this way.
>
> The notes then flip the symbol around and write $|S| > |T|$. I assume this just means exactly the same thing, but in reverse. Namely, $|S| < |T|$ if and only if $|T| < |S|$. So there is an injection $T \to S$ but no surjection $T \to S$.

Are all of these correct?

Comment: Seems about right, though I was never under the impression that $| \cdot |$ was nonstandard for "potentially infinite sets."

Comment: You should check the source. In some sources, $|S|\gt |T|$ means "there is a surjection $S\to T$ but no bijection/injection". The equivalence of "there is a surjection from $S$ to $T$" with "there is an injection from $T$ to $S$" may depend on the axiom of choice.

Comment: $|\cdot|$ is entirely standard for the cardinality of any set.